# How to change object variables in for loop in python

Tags: python, loops, reference

I'm not sure, whether it's an easy problem with easy solution or it's something that needs to dig a little deeper.

Let's say I have an object `Item` with variables `Item.a` and `Item.b`.
Now I have two instances of these objects: `Item1` and `Item2`

What I need is something like this:

```
for (value_1, value_2) in [(Item1.a, Item2.a), (Item1.b, Item2.b)]:
    if value_1 != value_2:
        value_1 = value_2
```

Of course this one is only an example of more complex problem. The substitution is ok, it finds differences between objects and substitutes them. The problem is, that all the time I'm doing it on copies of those variables, not on object references. As soon as it finish the loop, I can print both `Item1` and `Item2` and they are the same as before loop.

Is there any possibility to pass references into a loop? I know how to do it with lists, but I could not find an answer to objects.

Comment: I've explained, that was only an example. Actually I'm comparing two instances I receive and update one of them with SOAP request. I don't create them - I can only change their variables. I used Item not to complicate the question and to ask only for what I needed.

Comment: If you're not comparing "class attributes", but are actually comparing "object attributes", then your question is misleading.  Please try to make your question look like  your real problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, `[(Item1.a, Item2.a), (Item1.b, Item2.b)]` just creates a list of tuples of some values. Already by creating this you loose the connection to `ItemX`. Your problem is not related to the loop.

Maybe you want

```
for prop in ('a', 'b'):
    i2prop = getattr(Item2, prop)
    if getattr(Item1, prop) != i2prop:
        setattr(Item1, prop, i2prop)
```

Or something similar but with passing `ItemX` to the loop too:

```
for x, y, prop in ((Item1, Item2, 'a'), (Item1, Item2, 'b')):
    yprop = getattr(y, prop)
    if getattr(x, prop) != yprop:
        setattr(x, prop, yprop)
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was lookinkg for. Even without passing Items into loops.